# How do you create a button that will display a random result from an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, button, random, onclick

I've been trying to create a button that will take a random name from an array, and display it on an html page. Been trying for a long while to get this to work, with no results. What gives?

As well, if you know the answer, how could I create another button that would display multiple results, instead of just one?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function postmessage(){
 return "Your new recruit is " + firstnames;

  var firstnames = ["John", "Jacob", "Eric", "Conroy", "Vincent", "Laurence", "Jack", "Harry",    "Richard", "Michael", "Kevin", "Daniel", "Cody", "Brody", "Chase", "Cash", "Norman", "Trevor", "Todd", "Ellis", "Quentin", "Zachary", "Bruce", "Sam", "Horace", "George", "Tom", "Tim", "Wallace", "Walter", "Alex", "Alan", "Sean", "Seamus", "Dudley", "Duke", "Damian", "Nash", "Horton", "Robert", "Mitchell", ];
  var firstnames = firstnames[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstnames.length)];
  var postmessage = "Your new recruit is " + firstnames;
 };
</script>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" value="Get Recruit" onClick="postmessage();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: u actually do not displaying result `var postmessage=` just assigned desired result to new variable. `return ` immediately exits from a function.

Comment: Why does your `postmessage()` function start with a `return` statement?  That means none of the other code in that function will execute.  Put the `return` statement at the end of the function.  And, once you call `postmessage()`, you have to do something with the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function postmessage() {
  var firstnames = ["John", "Jacob", "Eric", "Conroy", "Vincent", "Laurence", "Jack", "Harry", "Richard", "Michael", "Kevin", "Daniel", "Cody", "Brody", "Chase", "Cash", "Norman", "Trevor", "Todd", "Ellis", "Quentin", "Zachary", "Bruce", "Sam", "Horace", "George", "Tom", "Tim", "Wallace", "Walter", "Alex", "Alan", "Sean", "Seamus", "Dudley", "Duke", "Damian", "Nash", "Horton", "Robert", "Mitchell", ];
  var firstname = firstnames[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstnames.length)];
  document.getElementById("recruit").textContent = "Your new recruit is " + firstname;
};
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Get Recruit" onclick="postmessage();" />
<div id="recruit"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I tried using the document.getElementById thing, but didn't use textContent in conjunction for it. Was searching this site for hours, and now I feel stupid. Kind of a JS newb, haha. Anyway, thanks again!